# youtube api for java/android, how to get started?

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to get started with youtube api for android... downloaded and imported the libraries so far, but wasn't able to find my code snippets.

Maybe you could suggest some simple ones, for example how execute a search query to youtube and get back the list of results? or something like that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

youtube have no specific API for Android. You can use [java api for youtube](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api).

Comment: yes, I'm trying to use that. well, any snippets would be cool. :)

Comment: are you planing to use java then these samples may help http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

Comment: Youtube does have a specific API for Android for youtube player and thumbnails though, not sure if that applies to the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the `google IO of this year (2012)` they announced the **youtube api** for Android apps, it isn't available yet, but it is going to be available soon, see the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y):

Answer (score 0):

Now it's available. You can download it from here : [YouTube Android API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just posted a new tutorial video on how to utilize the YouTube player and thumbnail in the YouTube for Android API.  The blog post with all the source code is [here](http://androiddev101.com/episode-12-youtube-it-all-night-long/)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube provides API to embed video into your Android application. You need to download YouTube API support library.

Fist step is to obtain Google API key from Developers Console.

Add YouTubePlayerView to your layout files and initialize it in your src file with API key generated for your application. After successful intialization of YouTubePlayerView, you will get object of YouTubePlayer which you can use to cue or control video.

You can check detailed step by step tutorial at

http://androidsrc.net/youtube-android-player-api-v1-2-1-embed-video-in-your-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial:
http://createdineden.com/blog/2015/may/12/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/
Hope it helps